# Run program over pty

Tags: shell, unix, groovy

I'm wondering if there was a standard unix program to force the allocation of a pty before executing a command.

Right now I'm using

```
ssh -tt localhost 'mycommand'
```

Which is a bit overkilled

I need this because groovy cannot allocate a pty, I don't really know why.

```
groovysh
'mycommand'.execute()
```

Fails because no pty is allocated

Note that I need the solution to be portable if possible, as I'll use it both under linux and solaris.

Thanks!

Comment: The `script` command may do what you want. On Linux, `script -q -e -c "your command" /dev/null`.

Comment: It does work on Linux, but Solaris doesn't have a GNU version of script.

Answer (score -1):

Gradle has an ssh plugin that you should be able to use.